# I have to update my password for the Server and Agent services every day

Tags: sql-server

Every day I have to go into Services, open the properties for the SQL Server and the SQL Server Agent, go to the Log On tab, and enter my current password.
I've checked the event viewer and I can't see anything that I recognize as potentially causing this, is there a setting I can use to not have to do this any more?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your account to Log on as Service in Local Security Policy.

[image]

Comment: Hi!  I am still working on this, the 'Add User or Group" is greyed out.

Comment: @Mithril28 Check with your IT dept.

Comment: I emailed them Friday, I'm waiting for confirmation.  Thank you!

Comment: It turns out I couldn't get permissions, so one of the techs said to just use Local Service without any password, and that is allowing me to connect to my local instance.  Thank you!!!